# Ebook app for Windows 8

Tags: windows, apps

I am looking for recommendations for an ebook application that runs on Windows 8/8.1 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the good old [ebook reader](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/viewer.html) bundled with Calibre. It's a multiplatform software, so it's available for other systems too, not just for Windows. Besides being a great application (Calibre itself is the swiss army knife for all things related to ebooks), it's also free and open-source.

There is also [EPUBReader](http://www.epubread.com/), it's not a standalone program but a Firefox extension. Anyway I've never used it so I can't tell you much more than this.

Other available ereaders are those tied to online ebook stores, like [Kindle](https://www.amazon.com/kindle-dbs/fd/kcp), [Kobo](https://www.kobo.com/desktop), [Nook](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/h/nook/apps), and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I've been playing with Calibre as of late, and it seems very useful. I just have some slight issues with the resulting text format, but nothing that can't be resolved by messing around with it a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

I like Readium, which is an extension for Google Chrome. Works best for me.

[TxtR](http://de.txtr.com/devices/windows-8/) is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions.html). It's free and will run on 8.1. It also supports EPUB 3. As long as there is no DRM, you can print from there too. It can open PDFs too.